# Attaching existing EC2 instance to new CloudFront in amazon aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudfront

I have a EC2 instance running in my account, now I need to add an SSL certificate to my web server running inside that EC2 instance.

Can I create a new cloudfront and attach my existing EC2 instance to it? Would that solve my purpose?

Comment: why this question negative voted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you make CloudFront point to an EC2 instance or any server really. Check out [Requiring HTTPS for Communication Between Viewers and CloudFront](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/using-https-viewers-to-cloudfront.html) for more information on how to do this.

Another option for free SSL certificates is [Let’s Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/). Super easy to setup and works with Apache and Nginx.

Comment: it's working fine but when i access the site using randometext.cloudfront.net it is showing in HTTPS and when I try to access it using my domain name like example.com it is in HTTP only. I have added my domain name in "Alternate Domain Names". What i should do here to make it working.

Comment: Not sure I fully understand. Does requesting your site using HTTPS give you a certificate error? Or is it just redirecting to HTTP?

Comment: I added cloudfront for making my website HTTPS, and the cloudfront url is coming with HTTPS but not my domain name.

Comment: You also need to add a DNS A record alias to point to the CloudFront distribution domain name within Route 53. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/resource-record-sets-values-alias.html#rrsets-values-alias-alias-target

Comment: I fixed it here is the solution: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-to-cloudfront-distribution.html, once again thanks all for the help!